# Why can not I append script to DOM on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript

Why can not I append script to DOM on mobile browsers. It looks like manipulating the dom is completely different in mobile browsers, but actually have no idea in what sense. I ve not got smth like that before, it was always ok. It also looks like the problem is not so actual, as I can not find a much proper info about it down here on stackoverflow. All suggestions to similar questions are mostly about syntax errors or even smth meaningless. In my code there are no mistakes, and this makes debugging really hard. Does anyone has an idea or maybe has encountered with smth like this?

```
function thumb_handler(data) {

    console.log(data);

    let icons = document.querySelectorAll('.messenger-wrap a span');

    for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {

        if (icons[i].getAttribute('class') == data.class) icons[i].style.background = 'url(' + data.img + ')';

    }

}

function requestServerCall(cls, img) {
    var head = document.head;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.text  = "alert('voila!');" 

    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://inmrkt/general.php?do=load_icons&callback=thumb_handler&class=' + cls + '&img=' + img);
    head.appendChild(script);
    // head.removeChild(script);
}


function icon_loader() {

    let icons = document.querySelectorAll('.messenger-wrap a span');

    for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {

        let img = icons[i].getAttribute('data-img'),
            cls = icons[i].getAttribute('class');

        requestServerCall(cls, img);

    }

}

icon_loader();
```

It is completely ok on any desktop, but not on mobiles. It just does not appear in the dom tree.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReI8E.png)

Comment: "on mobile browsers" — Which mobile browsers are you testing this in? What operating systems are you using?

Comment: it does not appear in the DOM tree? does your PHP script load a different layout, or only loads specific portions of code based on the browser requesting the page?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML file including it?

Comment: "It looks like manipulating the dom is completely different in mobile browsers" — What tools are you using to determine this?

Comment: You've tagged this question with [tag:php]: Why?

Comment: Are you transpiling es6 syntax? Does `let` work on the device you are testing?

Comment: please, see the img i ve added to description, I clearly shows that php works well, and all 3 scripts are being added succesfully. But that is on desktop. There is nothing similar in mobile browsers. Mobile browsers: iOS Opera, iOS Safari, iOS Dolphin, Android Chrome.

Comment: As to "let" - I ve tried with "var" many times - no effect

Comment: `smth meaningless` - ironic ... anyway, so what do you expect `script.text  = "alert('voila!');"` will do? also why do you set script type with `script.type` but script src using `script.setAttribute('src', ...` - why not `script.src=...` (try it)

Comment: by the way, your code works fine on android chrome and firefox, I don't have access to any iOS devices at the moment, so I can't say that apple works

Comment: `clearly shows that php works well` - there is no spoon ... nor any php posted

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe just to test? and btw what difference should appear by changing `setAttribute('src'` to a `.src` according to you? Just random stuff I guess

Comment: none, I was just wondering why you use one method for one attribute and a different one for another attribute - and as I don't have access to apple device, perhaps it makes a difference for apples excuse for a browser - as I said, your code adds the javascript correctly (though, don't expect the alert to ever actually alert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to make the code work on a server without checking twice if any stuff for local environment is still present.

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://inmrkt/general.php?do=load_icons&callback=thumb_handler&class=' + cls + '&img=' + img);
```

url obviously points to a localhost domain... And should be as following:

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com/general.php?do=load_icons&callback=thumb_handler&class=' + cls + '&img=' + img);
```

or

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'general.php?do=load_icons&callback=thumb_handler&class=' + cls + '&img=' + img);
```